# Erratum in Griffiths Electrodynamics (wrong reference is made)

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, vector-fields, textbook-erratum

I have the Fourth Edition of **Introduction to Electrodynamics** by **David J. Griffiths**, published by Pearson.

I have found this erratum in Chapter 5 Magnetostatics, page 234 .

[image] We can see that "Product rule number 6" is written and no asterisk or dagger is there, so I looked in Chapter 1 and found this on page 21

[image] The "rule" which he is using is actually rule number 4.

I have seen the list of errata in the [official site](https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/griffiths/) but couldn't find it.

Comment: Yes, that is a valid erratum. But you didn’t ask a question.

Comment: @G.Smith :) I don’t know what to say but I think I have done for clarification and to spread awareness also :)

Comment: Editing your [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/529907/) would have been more appropriate.

Comment: This isn't a mistake, Griffiths is talking about equation 6 on the inside front cover, where all these results are listed for reference. (That's why they're numbered on page 21 with _Roman_ numerals instead. "(iv)" isn't the same thing as "6".)